# Regex parse key value pair from a shortcode tag

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a javascript Regular expression to parse shortcodes and their contents, but now I'm trying to modify it to also parse out a key/value pair from the tag's attributes.

Example:

```
[shortcode name="test"]
the shortcode conents
[/shortcode]
```

I would like to receive the following matches:

- tag name (`shortcode`)
- tag attributes, without quotes (`name=test`)
- tag contents (`the shortcode contents`)

My regular expression is currently: `/\[([^\]]*?)\]([\s\S]*?)\[\/\1\]/ig`

Which will take:

```
[shortcode]
the shortcode contents
[/shortcode]
```

and return

- `shortcode`
- `the shortcode contents`

So now I am trying to get the attributes, and we can also assume the key `name` is consistent, so we won't expect any other key value pairs, just `name="something"` is fine.

Comment: try `str.match(/\[(\S+)\s+(.+)=(['"])(.+)\3\]([\s\S]*?)\[\/\1\]/i)`

Comment: @Yukulélé that works, however it is capturing one quote as another match. I tried to modify it not to, but had no luck

Comment: you can avoid it with "?:" `str.match(/\[(\S+)\s+(.+)=(?:['"])(?:.+)\3\]([\s\S]*?)\[\/\1\]/i)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do this in two regexes ([fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nnWgr/))

```
var split_bits = /\[([^\]]+)]([^\[]+)\[\/([^\]]+)]/ig,
    bits = split_bits.exec( shortcode );

var split_arguments = /([a-zA-Z]+)="([^"]+)+"/gi,
    arguments = split_arguments.exec( bits[1] );
```

The first grabs the shortcode tag name & contents. And then passes the first part of the shortcode to the second regex which locates the arguments.

Note: still working on parsing multiple arguments.